# How could I use "tr" to translate every byte?

Tags: linux, bash

My goal is to have every byte from an input file xor with 42 using tr.
But I was stuck at this point:

```
tr '\0-\377' '?'
```

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot..

Some restrictions:

translation has to be done by tr.

we are allowed to use bash script, but it shouldn’t use any temporary files. (only pipeline in other words)

Comment: I think a Perl solution might serve you better - maybe tag with Perl if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping last night. I've added a follow up.

Comment: @yantiz: for future reference, it's a good idea to be around to babysit your question for the first hour or so after you ask, at least.  If it's missing an important clarification, it could be downvoted to hell before you look at it again.  Luckily this question didn't have that problem, but knowing that this was a homework question where you were restricted to `bash` and `tr` is a pretty important constraint.

Comment: Certainly I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with `tr` alone since it - as the name says - simply translates from one codeset to another. Math calculations or logical operations are not supported.

Btw, if you want to address the whole ascii range using numeric values, you are bound to octal numbers. The range would be `\0-\377` in that case. But anyway, calculating the xor value is not possible.

What you can do is the prepare a table with xor^42'ed ascii values and use as SET2. I'm using python to create that list:

*xor.py*

```
v = []
for i in range(0,255):
    v.append("\\" + oct(i^42))
print("".join(v))
```

Or simply:

```
print("".join(["\\" + oct(i^42) for i in range(0,255)]))
```

Then use that to create SET2 for `tr`:

```
tr '\0-\0377' "$(python xor.py)" < input.file
```

---

Note: When python is already required, why not using python for the whole solution?

**Edited by Mark Setchell**

As [Peter pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648328/how-could-i-use-tr-to-translate-every-byte/33649486#comment55091603_33649486) this list can of course getting generated in advance and then getting passed as a string for SET2. This would not require a runtime python call. Like this:

```
tr '\0-\0377' '\052\053\050\051\056\057\054\055\042\043\040\041\046\047\044\045\072\073\070\071\076\077\074\075\062\063\060\061\066\067\064\065\012\013\010\011\016\017\014\015\02\03\0\01\06\07\04\05\032\033\030\031\036\037\034\035\022\023\020\021\026\027\024\025\0152\0153\0150\0151\0156\0157\0154\0155\0142\0143\0140\0141\0146\0147\0144\0145\0172\0173\0170\0171\0176\0177\0174\0175\0162\0163\0160\0161\0166\0167\0164\0165\0112\0113\0110\0111\0116\0117\0114\0115\0102\0103\0100\0101\0106\0107\0104\0105\0132\0133\0130\0131\0136\0137\0134\0135\0122\0123\0120\0121\0126\0127\0124\0125\0252\0253\0250\0251\0256\0257\0254\0255\0242\0243\0240\0241\0246\0247\0244\0245\0272\0273\0270\0271\0276\0277\0274\0275\0262\0263\0260\0261\0266\0267\0264\0265\0212\0213\0210\0211\0216\0217\0214\0215\0202\0203\0200\0201\0206\0207\0204\0205\0232\0233\0230\0231\0236\0237\0234\0235\0222\0223\0220\0221\0226\0227\0224\0225\0352\0353\0350\0351\0356\0357\0354\0355\0342\0343\0340\0341\0346\0347\0344\0345\0372\0373\0370\0371\0376\0377\0374\0375\0362\0363\0360\0361\0366\0367\0364\0365\0312\0313\0310\0311\0316\0317\0314\0315\0302\0303\0300\0301\0306\0307\0304\0305\0332\0333\0330\0331\0336\0337\0334\0335\0322\0323\0320\0321\0326\0327\0324' < inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: What if we are allowed to use bash script instead of python? Sorry for the late response, and thank you for your reply.

Comment: You are welcome. Are you searching for something like this: http://zurlinux.com/?p=712

Comment: Not really...To be honest, this question comes from my homework and we are restricted to use tr to translate each byte from input to another byte using xor with 42. It indeed drives me crazy and I am totally stuck. The optimal format will be something like this: cat | tr ? ?

Comment: @yantiz: You don't have to re-generate SET2 at runtime.  You could run the python script on your desktop once, and then hardcode that into the script that runs `tr`.  BTW, if you're xoring a lot of data, do it with `tr`, not directly with with bash `read`.

Comment: I agree with Mark's idea, and the python solution given by hek2mgl is also very helpful. I am sorry that my homework requirements are stupid and tedious. In the end, thank you guys so much.